# Javascript object prototype function

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

I have three methods in an object.

2 of them work properly, when third is printed - it prints out the code itself, not function. Here is the code and how it looks in console:

```js
function Students(name, lastname, grades){
    this.name = name;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.grades = grades;
    this.addGrade = function(a){
        this.grades.push(a);
    }
    this.printData = function(){
        console.log("Name: " + this.name);
        console.log("Grades: " + this.grades);
        console.log("Average: " + this.gradeAvg);
    }
    this.gradeAvg = function(){
        console.log("blabla");
    }
}

var StudentasA = new Students("Petras", "Petrauskas", [8, 9, 9, 8, 7]);
var StudentasB = new Students("Jurgis", "Jurgauskas", [6, 7, 5, 4, 9]);
StudentasA.printData();
StudentasA.addGrade(28);
StudentasA.printData();
```

console:

[console view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKc2K.png)

Comment: You aren't actually using a prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function

```
this.gradeAvg()
//           ^^
```

```js
function Students(name, lastname, grades){
    this.name = name;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.grades = grades;
    this.addGrade = function(a){
        this.grades.push(a);
    }
    this.printData = function(){
        console.log("Name: " + this.name);
        console.log("Grades: " + this.grades);
        console.log("Average: " + this.gradeAvg());
        //                                     ^^
    }
    this.gradeAvg = function(){
        return this.grades.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }) / this.grades.length;
    }
}

var StudentasA = new Students("Petras", "Petrauskas", [8, 9, 9, 8, 7]);
var StudentasB = new Students("Jurgis", "Jurgauskas", [6, 7, 5, 4, 9]);
StudentasA.printData();
StudentasA.addGrade(28);
StudentasA.printData();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code never actually calls the function.

Instead, you concatenate the function itself directly into the string.

You want parentheses.